# My Canon PowershotSX260 HS shows an error message

Tags: lens, camera

I accidentally droped my Canon PowershotSX260 HS while I was using it. The camera's lens was still extended but the camera looked like it just powered off. I tried pushing the power button, but when I did it, it showed the starting screen, then made a weird sound almost as if I hard shut down it. It then beeped a few times and then a message popped up on the screen saying:

**Lens Error**

**Will shut down automatically**

**Restart camera**

I have treated this camera very well and have never even got a scratch on it. I removed the SD card and the battery. Good news, everything is saved on the SD card still but I need my camera. What do I do?

Answer (score 1):

The camera is broken. Professional repair is almost certainly more expensive than the cost of replacement with a used camera with similar capabilities. Professional repair is probably even more expensive than replacement with a new camera of similar ergonomics.

It may be possible to repair the camera yourself depending on your tools, capabilities, and the nature of the damage. And there is not much to lose since the camera is broken.

However replacement will get you back making pictures again. Cameras break if they are used. It doesn’t make anyone happy when it happens. But nearly all cameras are replaceable and the important part is the pictures not the tool that made them.

Comment: Yeah, but I really do not want to get a new one. I really just want to fix it. This camera is very important to me and I do not want to get one. Is there a way I can reset the lens or something like that. Thank you for answering.

Comment: @Ben it appears to be broken. Maybe it can be fixed. Find a repair shop and ask. Or take it apart and try yourself. Or put it on a shelf and use something else. Cameras break.